# How can I define an Elisp widget type that only accepts positive numbers?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to have a custom variable in my Emacs package, and the only valid values for that variable are positive integers. Is there a way to make it so that M-x customize will only accept positive integers for this variable and refuse others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out how to do this with the custom variable's `:validate` property:

```
(defun widget-positive-integer-validate (widget)
  (let ((v (widget-value widget)))
    (if (natnump v)
        ;; Valid
        nil
      ;; Invalid
      (widget-put widget :error "This field should contain a positive integer")
      widget))))

(defcustom positive-integer-var 5000
  "This variable must be a positive integer."
  :type '(integer :value 5000
                  :validate widget-positive-integer-validate))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to use restricted-sexp as :type.

```
:type `(restricted-sexp
        :match-alternatives
        (,(lambda (v) (and (natnump v) (/= v 0))))))
```

muede

Comment: Will this give an informative error message if the user puts in a negative integer or a string or anything else?